# How to define continuous linear functional in the space of section of a vector bundle?

Tags: distribution-theory, vector-bundles

By definition, a distribution on $U\subset R $ is a continuous linear functional on $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$
where $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ is space of test function.

So in order to define a distribution we have to define a topology in $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$.

Now let $\Gamma(E)$ be a space of section of a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$.

How we define continuos linear functional in this space of section?